# Add class to page content output

Tags: theming, 7

I have the following snippet in a theme's page.tpl.php:

```
<div id="content-wrap" class="row">
          <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
          <?php if ($title): ?><h1 class="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1><?php endif; ?>
          <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
          <?php if (!empty($tabs['#primary'])): ?><div class="tabs-wrapper clearfix"><?php print render($tabs); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
          <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
          <?php if ($action_links): ?><ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
          <?php print "**59**". render($page['content'])."**88**"; ?>
        </div>
```

The starred numbers in the last line for debugging. The output of `render($page['content'])` is something like the follwoing:

```
<div class="region region-content">
  <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">
.....
```

What I need to perform is programmatically change or add class name to `<div class="region region-content">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a module/theme by adding a region preprocess hook:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['region'] == 'content') {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'foo';
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean template.php file?

Comment: Yes - add that, replace `MYTHEME` with name of your theme, and clear the caches. Hopefully you should see the changes straight away

Comment: Thank you very much. I found another way to do this by modifying `<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> foo">` in region.tpl.php. My theme contain this file, if it is not found in the theme we are able to overwrite it by copying it from modules/system/ and placing it the theme directory.